# Is there a way to calculate a particular sheet in excel using python?

Tags: excel, pywin32, xlwings

I need to calculate a sheet of interest in excel using python. There is a method to calculate the entire workbook using the following code.

```
import xlwings as xw
book = xw.Book(file_path)
book.app.calculate()
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same for a single sheet? Tried

```
book.sheets["Sheet 1"].calculate
```

but sheet object has no "calculate" attribute.

**Edit**.
Tried the following too.

```
import win32com.client 
xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(file_path)
wb.Worksheets('Page 2').Calculate()
```

This doesn't give any error but doesn't work either.

**Edit-2**
Found the answer finally, been missing "EnableCalculation = True. "

```
import win32com.client 
xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(file_path)
ws = wb.Worksheets('Page 2')
ws.EnableCalculation = True 
wb.Worksheets('Page 2').Calculate()
```

Comment: Suggest using `win32com` directly then you will have access to the Worksheet.Calculate method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a similar question [here](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/1254).  The solution (for now) is to use `api.Calculate()`, so you don't need to enable calculations to do this.

So in your second example code, you could instead run:

```
wb.sheets["Sheet 1"].api.Calculate()
```